# Fetching from API and updating the state of React comp

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I have a component that represents a basemap from ESRI ArcGIS Api. I try to update the longitute and latitude coordinates of the map by fetching info from another API and updating the coords using fetch and setState. This is my component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map  } from 'react-arcgis';

class Basemap extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json';
        fetch(url)
            .then((d) => {
                this.setState({
                    center: [{d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + {d.iss_position.longitude}]
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Map style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} 
                    mapProperties={{ basemap: 'satellite' }} 
                    viewProperties={{ this.state.center }} />
        );
    }
}

export default Basemap;
```

However, I get this error:

```
./src/components/basemap.js
Syntax error: components/basemap.js: Unexpected token, expected , (16:16)

  14 |          .then((d) => {
  15 |              this.setState({
> 16 |                  center: [{d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + {d.iss_position.longitude}]
     |                             ^
  17 |              });
  18 |          });
  19 |  }
```

Am I missing something in the fetch function?

Comment: check the type of d. Is it data object u r expecting or not?

Comment: Check this answer for detailed fetch API explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667764/reactrest-api-storing-form-data-into-an-object-on-the-rest-api/45667924#45667924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are getting from `fetch` is not the JSON response you are expecting.

```
fetch('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      center: [...]
    })
})
```

Also, you are concatenating the result wrongly:

If center is lat, lng:

```
this.setState({
  center: [d.iss_position.latitude, d.iss_position.longitude]
})
```

or

```
this.setState({
  center: `${d.iss_position.latitude}, ${d.iss_position.longitude}`
})
```

or

```
this.setState({
  center: {
    latitude: d.iss_position.latitude,
    longitude: d.iss_position.longitude
  }
})
```

depending on what the response should be.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't get any error now, but the map is still zoomed to a default location and not taking new coordinates.. Veeery strange.

Comment: Try to `console.log` the result and compare to check whether they are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Unexpected token, expected ,

There is an issue with [`Shorthand property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Assuming, you are using `latitude` and `longitude` then it should be

```
 center: [
          {latitude : d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + 
          {longitude: d.iss_position.longitude}
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json';
    fetch(url)
        .then((d) => {
            this.setState({
                center: [{latitude : d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + {longitude: d.iss_position.longitude}]
            });
        });
}
```