# ReactJS fetchAPI JSON type - TypeError: content.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, metismenu

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-metismenu for metismenu and using fetch api to get response from service. I get the response properly but getting below exception

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `content` of type `object` supplied to `MetisMenu`, expected an array
TypeError: content.forEach is not a function
```

The service code:

```
@GET
    @Path("/menu")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getMenuItems(@QueryParam("industry") String industry) {
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray();
        try{
            org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
            obj.put("icon", "spinner");
            obj.put("label", "User Maintenance");
            obj.put("to", "#a-link");
            response.put(obj);

            org.json.JSONArray content = new org.json.JSONArray();
            obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
            obj.put("icon", "apple");
            obj.put("label", "System Controls");
            obj.put("to", "#b1-link");
            content.put(obj);
            obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
            obj.put("icon", "user");
            obj.put("label", "User Maintenance");
            obj.put("to", "#b2-link");
            content.put(obj);

            obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
            obj.put("icon", "gear");
            obj.put("label", "System Preferences");
            obj.put("content", content);            
            response.put(obj);

            obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
            obj.put("icon", "gear");
            obj.put("label", "Configuration");
            obj.put("to", "#c-link");
            response.put(obj);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

and the index.js code:

```
var content=fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc').then(function(response){
         return response
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <MetisMenu content={content} activeLinkFromLocation />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If I hardcode the const value then it works fine.

Got it working, the issue was CORS so I avoided CORS in my other application's web.xml whose service I am using. And changed the code with below part:

```
export default class MenuComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.data.map(menu => (
    {
      to: `${menu.to}`,
      icon: `${menu.icon}`,
      label: `${menu.label}`
      // content: `${menu.content}`
    }
  )))
  .then(content => this.setState({
    content
  }))
}

  render() {
    console.log('333');
    console.log(this.state.content);
    return (
      <MetisMenu content={this.state.content} activeLinkFromLocation />
    )
  }
}
```

The only issue now is that nested content within content is not working, can anyone please help me.
I also tried the ajax mentioned in https://github.com/alpertuna/react-metismenu, and it also didnt work.

Comment: it loosk like your response is an object, not an array

Comment: When I hit the service on browser then it returns proper jsonarray while I tried the console.log() in reactjs then it is showing *promise* object within lot of objects

Answer (score 0):

Since `fetch` returns a promise, you need to wait while it's resolved using `Promise.then` or `await` approach.

```
var content = await fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc');
```

I suggest you wrap this fetching code in a separate component and pass the response to the setState method.

SomeComponent.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      content: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
    .then((response) => this.setState({ content: response }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <MetisMenu content={this.state.content} activeLinkFromLocation />
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```js
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent';
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that didnt throw an error but still data is not loaded in page. When I log the response from service then it is showing content as empty array

Comment: Do you log response like this: componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
    .then((response) => { console.log(response); this.setState({ content: response }));
  }

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
    .then((response) => this.setState({ content: response }));
    console.log(this.state.content);
  }

Comment: That's correct that you see empty array in console. Since `this.setState` is acync, new value for content is not applied to state. Try to put `console.log(this.state.content)` in the `render`  method.

Comment: The result is same empty array

Comment: Could you try to open network tab in your browser and check if the request is sent to the server and what is the response when you reload page?

Comment: Response payload - ["{\"to\":\"#a-link\",\"icon\":\"spinner\",\"label\":\"User Maintenance\"}","{\"content\":[{\"to\":\"#b1-link\",\"icon\":\"apple\",\"label\":\"System Controls\"},{\"to\":\"#b2-link\",\"icon\":\"user\",\"label\":\"User Maintenance\"}],\"icon\":\"gear\",\"label\":\"System Preferences\"}","{\"to\":\"#c-link\",\"icon\":\"gear\",\"label\":\"Configuration\"}"]

Comment: Also I think CORS is the issue, I get below error on Chrome - 
localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.0.32:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I tried with {mode:'no-cors'} also but still the object is empty.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979617/fetching-from-api-and-updating-the-state-of-react-comp# is working fine, but when I put mode:no-cors here also then it doesnt work. Is there any other way to set no-cors

Comment: I got it working, with some changes. Please look at the updated post, the issue now is nested array

Comment: What do you mean as "is not working"? What is the output for `console.log(this.state.content)` in render method?

Comment: How to map the nested array I mean content within content - {"data":[{"to":"#a-link","icon":"spinner","label":"User Maintenance"},{"content":[{"to":"#b1-link","icon":"apple","label":"System Controls"},{"to":"#b2-link","icon":"user","label":"User Maintenance"}],"icon":"gear","label":"System Preferences"},{"to":"#c-link","icon":"gear","label":"Configuration"}]}

Comment: Asked question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778908/how-to-use-fetchapi-nested-arrays-of-same-object