# How to use FetchAPI nested Arrays of same object

Tags: reactjs, metismenu

I am trying to show menu where it can have parent child relationship, with flat structure it is working fine but with nested objects not able to do it.
The below is the JSON and reactJS code. 
JSON -

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "to": "#a-link",
      "icon": "spinner",
      "label": "User Maintenance"
    },
    {
      "content": [
        {
          "to": "#b1-link",
          "icon": "apple",
          "label": "System Controls"
        },
        {
          "to": "#b2-link",
          "icon": "user",
          "label": "User Maintenance"
        }
      ],
      "icon": "gear",
      "label": "System Preferences"
    },
    {
      "to": "#c-link",
      "icon": "gear",
      "label": "Configuration"
    }
  ]
}
```

ReactJS code -

```
export default class MenuComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.data.map(menu => (
    {
      to: `${menu.to}`,
      icon: `${menu.icon}`,
      label: `${menu.label}`
      // content: `${menu.content}`
    }
  )))
  .then(content => this.setState({
    content
  }))
}

  render() {
    console.log('333');
    console.log(this.state.content);
    return (
      <MetisMenu content={this.state.content} activeLinkFromLocation />
    )
  }
}
```

In JSON you can see the 'System Preference' has nested content.

Comment: Did you try with initiating content as a state in the constructor?

Comment: You can just do another .map on menu.content.map(menuContentItem => ... etc

Comment: @SumanKundu - I am newbie to reactjs, please help me how to do it.

Comment: @GavinThomas - We can do it, but what if the recurrency is at multiple levels like 4-5

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 class MenuComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    content : []
    }
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:8084/Accounting/rest/v1/company/menu?request=abc')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.data.map(menu => (
    {
      to: `${menu.to}`,
      icon: `${menu.icon}`,
      label: `${menu.label}`
      // content: `${menu.content}`
    }
  )))
  .then(content => this.setState({
    content
  }))
}

  render() {
    const {content} = this.state
    if(content === undefined){
      return <div>Content not found</div>;
    }
    if(content.length === 0){
     return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
    return (
            <MetisMenu content={content} activeLinkFromLocation />
    )
  }
}
export default MenuComponent
```

Comment: The index and cont are undefined variables. Please let me know where we need to define them and how

Comment: Same issue only flat structure is coming up, within System Preference it is not showing the child menu items

Comment: I am using the react-metismenu component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-metismenu), not sure where to change the second part

Comment: Ok then it must work without the second part.what exactly displaying now

Comment: The child menu items are not shown within System Prefernces